# How can I tell how many bytes have been sent?

Tags: php, header, buffer, filestream, fread

```
  function Ifurl($subject)
     {
    $pattern = "/http:\/\//";
    $regex = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $array);
    if ($regex == 1)
    {
        return true; //true that it exist
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

    function get_start_point($env_http_range)
{
    //Calculate start point
    $range = $env_http_range; // usually set to $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']
    if ($range != '')
    {
        $p1 = strpos($range, "bytes=");
        $p2 = strpos($range, "-");
        $offset = substr($range, $p1+6, $p2-($p1+6));
    } else {
        $offset = 0;
    }


    return $offset;
}


   function Output($url,$range,$range2) //cant record output 8192 not full amount 

   {
   $opts    = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",'header'=>"Range: bytes=$range-$range2"));

   $context = stream_context_create($opts);
   $fp      = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
   while(!feof($fp) && !connection_aborted())
   {
   $data_transferred += 1024 * 8;
   fpassthru($fp);
   }
   $status = (!connection_aborted());
   log_this($data_transferred);
   fclose($httphandle);
    }

    function log_this($line)
{
    $filename = 'download_log.txt';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
    fwrite($handle, $line . "\n");
}


function url($url)
{
    $define_url = Ifurl($url); //define if the url is true!
    if ($define_url == 1)
    {
        $filename    = basename($url); //define the filename of the file
        $httphandle  = fopen($url, "r"); //open the file and read the information
        $headers     = stream_get_meta_data($httphandle);
        $filesize    = $headers['wrapper_data'][6]; //define the file conent size
        $filecontent = $headers['wrapper_data'][8]; //get the file content
        $pattern     = "/(\d+)/"; //get all filesize dg
        preg_match_all($pattern, $filesize, $array);
        $filesize    = $array[0][0]; //get the filesize;
        $returnarray  = array("Filename" => $filename,"Filesize" => $filesize, "Fileurl" => $url,"Filecontent" => $filecontent);
        return $returnarray;
    }
    else
    {

        return "Unable"; //unable to make request!
    }

}



function XD($url)
{

$graburl     = url($url);
$filename    = $graburl['Filename'];
$filesize    = $graburl['Filesize'];
$filurl      = $graburl['Fileurl'];
$filecontent = $graburl['Filecontent'];

///////////////////////////////////////////
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');
ob_end_clean();
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
ignore_user_abort(true);


//////////////////////////////////////////// 


@header("Cache-Control:");
@header("Cache-Control: public");
@header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
@header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
@header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");


  $log  = get_start_point($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
    log_this($log);

  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) 
  {
    list($a, $range)=explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
    list($range1,$range2) = explode("-", $range);
    if ($range2 == '' or $range2 < 0 or $range2 >= $filesize) {
        $range2 = $filesize -1;
    };
    if ($range1 < 0 or $range1 > $range2) {
        $range1 = 0;
    }
    $new_length = $range2 - $range1 + 1;

    @header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    @header("Content-Range: bytes $range1-$range2/$filesize");
    @header("Content-Length: $new_length");


    Output($url,$range1,$range2);

}
 else {
    @header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);

       $httphandle  = fopen($url, "r"); //open the file and read the information
       while (!feof($httphandle) && !connection_aborted())
       {
       $data_transferred += 1024 * 8;
       echo fread($httphandle, 1024 * 8);
          flush();
       ob_end_flush();
      }
      $status = (!connection_aborted());
      log_this($data_transferred);
      fclose($httphandle);
}

  }


XD('http://rarlabs.com/rar/wrar393.exe')
```

I am trying to resume the download and record the bytes that has been downloaded using a buffer the code works great! But I am unable to record full amount of bytes downloaded from the user, the function Output talks to the server to send bytes that the user has left off  I am recording it with a text file as a test, when the user downloads it logs the bytes that the user downloads an save it to a text file however the only problem is when the user calls the function output the log doesnt record how much bytes I try using fread but the code goes into choas how can I log the user for the total amount of bytes downloaded?

Comment: I suggest you use full stops. I didn't understand the problem. What does this mean "when the user calls he function out?"?

Comment: function Output($url,$range,$range2)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this function out in the docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#84115

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the curl extension?

Comment: curl i wanna know how to log the user of how much bytes the user downlaoded

Comment: I'm pretty sure curl can track bytes transferred. Go read the documentation.

Comment: i did can you explain how it would be possible then, to track bytes when a user downloads a file

Comment: Do you want to know how many bytes have been used in a server-to-server manner or how many the from the user to your server? In the case of the latter, PHP is probably the wrong tool. You want something at the webserver level.